# Group Multiple lists based on multiple factors

Tags: python, list

New to Python...

If i have an output file (firewall log file) that looks like:

```
(source)    (dest)    (proto) (service)

10.10.10.1    20.20.20.1    TCP 80
10.10.10.1    30.30.30.1    TCP 80
10.10.10.1    40.40.40.1    TCP 514
10.10.10.1    40.40.40.1    TCP 443
```

I need to group this data based on 3 of the 4 that match. So based on the above output, I need this written to a new file that looks like

```
10.10.10.1    20.20.20.1;30.30.30.1    TCP 80

                 OR
10.10.10.1    40.40.40.1    TCP 514, 443
```

(please note the use of semicolon to separate IP address, and in the second line a comma is used to separate the service objects)

I've reviewed the python groupby method, but I just can't get the syntax correct

So in English(in my head):

```
for every line in the file,
    if source and/or dest and/or proto, and/or service match any other line in  
     line in the file
        combine on one line and write to file (with semicolon if separting IP
        addresses and a comma if separating service objects)

import re
from itertools import groupby
from sys import argv
#Written by Clyde Colbert - f7cmb14

script, filename = argv

data = []

def connection_list(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            text = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print(filename, "Does not exist in the current directory. Are you in the correct directory???")

    sources = re.findall(r'src=(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
    dest = re.findall(r'dst=(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
    service = re.findall(r'service=(\d+)', text)
    proto = re.findall(r'proto=(\w+)', text)

    proto = [item.upper() for item in proto]
    sources = [item.split('=')[1] for item in sources]
    dest = [item.split('=')[1] for item in dest]

    with open(filename + "OUTPUT.txt", "w") as TufinReq:
        for item in zip(sources, dest, proto, service):
            TufinReq.write('{}\t{}\t{} {}\n'.format(*item))

    f=open(filename + "OUTPUT.txt", "r")
    list = []
    for line in f:
        if line not in list:
            list.append(line)
    f.close()
    f=open(filename + "OUTPUT.txt", "w+")
    for line in list:
        f.write(line)
    f.close()

    f=open(filename + "Output.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)

cols = (0,2,3)
def getcolumns(cols):
    cols = (0,2,3)
    def f(row):
        return tuple(row[i] for i in cols)
    return f

for k, v in groupby(data, getcolumns(cols)):
    print(k, list(v))

connection_list(filename)
```

Comment: What if you have lines `A B C; A B D; E B D`? Which lines should be grouped?

Comment: In your example - Lines 1 & 2 should be grouped - To apply to my specific issue, this would equate to the same source IP accessing the same destination IP just on different ports. i.e 10.10.10.1 >> 20.20.20.1 port80 & 10.10.10.1 >> 20.20.20.1 port443

Answer (score 0):

`groupby(iterable, keyfunc)` works by grouping for items with the same `key` (the value returned by the `keyfunc`.

To accomplish your task, you can make keyfunc return multiple items of a row.

Let's suppose for simplicity that you already have your data in the format:

```
data=[
('10.10.10.1', '20.20.20.1', 'TCP', '80'),
('10.10.10.1', '30.30.30.1', 'TCP', '80'),
('10.10.10.1', '40.40.40.1', 'TCP', '514'),
('10.10.10.1', '40.40.40.1', 'TCP', '443')
]
```

So if you want to see rows where source, proto and service match (column indices 0, 2 and 3), you would make a key of those columns.

Let's write a little closure to extract those columns (it will be your keyfunc):

```
def getcolumns(cols):
    def f(row):
        return tuple(row[i] for i in cols)
    return f
```

Let's look at the result you get:

```
>>> cols = (0,2,3)
>>> data.sort(key=getcolumns(cols))
>>> for k, v in groupby(data, getcolumns(cols)):
...     print(k, list(v))
...
('10.10.10.1', 'TCP', '80') [('10.10.10.1', '20.20.20.1', 'TCP', '80'), ('10.10.10.1', '30.30.30.1', 'TCP', '80')]
('10.10.10.1', 'TCP', '514') [('10.10.10.1', '40.40.40.1', 'TCP', '514')]
('10.10.10.1', 'TCP', '443') [('10.10.10.1', '40.40.40.1', 'TCP', '443')]
```

You may want to exclude results where the grouper has length 1 (no matches):

```
>>> cols = (0,2,3)
>>> data.sort(key=getcolumns(cols))
>>> for k, v in groupby(data, getcolumns(cols)):
...     v = list(v)
...     if len(v) == 1: continue
...     print(k, v)
...
('10.10.10.1', 'TCP', '80') [('10.10.10.1', '20.20.20.1', 'TCP', '80'), ('10.10.10.1', '30.30.30.1', 'TCP', '80')]
```

Now it takes only a bit of processing to turn this into the output format you are looking for:

```
>>> cols = (0,2,3)
>>> data.sort(key=getcolumns(cols))
>>> for k, v in groupby(data, getcolumns(cols)):
...     v = list(v)
...     if len(v) == 1: continue
...     print(*(';'.join(set(r[i] for r in v)) for i in range(len(v[0]))))
...
10.10.10.1 20.20.20.1;30.30.30.1 TCP 80
```

(use an [OrderedSet](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) if you want to use this implementation but you want to retain the order of rows)

Comment: `groupby` assumes that the data are already sorted.  The OP's example data set does not need to be sorted, but other logs presumably will need you to pre-`sort` the data using the same keyfunc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. however, I am still having trouble, let me share my code with you. I do understand my code is probably inefficiently written but I'm new and trying to take it step by step.  I tried to add, per your suggestion but it does nothing, I am doing something wrong.